Understanding the witness property in the Henkin construction
I'm trying to get a really good intuition for why the proof of the compactness theorem via the Henkin construction in Marker's model theory uses the witness property, specifically, why use
For every formula $\phi$, there is a constant symbol $c$ such that:
$$T \models (\exists v\phi(v)\rightarrow\phi(c))$$
Or perhaps, as per Definition of witness property in Marker's "Model theory - An introduction":
$$T \ni (\exists v\phi(v)\rightarrow\phi(c))$$
And not the naive version:
For every formula $\phi$ with $T \ni(\exists v\phi(v))$, there is a constant $c$ with $\phi(c)\in T$.
Reading through Witness property implies scapegoat theory in first-order logic, it's clear these are different, but as far as I can tell, they aren't different in the case that $T$ is maximal.
So why not construct a maximal, finitely satisfiable theory, with the witness property out of a starting theory $T$ by alternating between:

Extending to a maximal theory
And adding in new constant symbols to witness just the formulas $\phi$ such that the current maximal theory contains $\exists v\phi(v)$.


I added the missing "$\in T$" in your "naive version".

You're correct that the two versions are equivalent when $T$ is complete (maximal), and your proposed argument (alternating between completing the theory and adding witnesses) works just fine.
In fact, if you want to work with semantics that allow empty structures, or semantics for multi-sorted logic that allow empty sorts, you are forced to take this approach. Adding a constant symbol of sort $S$ before knowing whether your completion of $T$ will prove that $S$ is non-empty prematurately rules out models in which $S$ is empty. For this reason, I took your approach in my notes on model theory here (see the proof of Lemma 3.9 on p. 29).
I think the reason many authors prefer the version with axioms $(\exists x\, \varphi(x))\to \varphi(c)$ is that after adding all the new constant symbols and new axioms expressing the witness property, we only need to complete the theory once.
